# Does nyaya or vaisheshikha school accept pratibhashik and paramarthik realities?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, nyaya

In one of the discourse I heard that Nyaya and Vaisheshikha accept 2 levels of reality.

However Shankaracharya was the 1st one to refute this claim of 2 level realities and established the 3rd reality viz. Vyavaharik.

However one of my friend told me that such notion is not there in nyaya school. That Nyaya doesn’t accept realities called “pratibhashik” and “paramarthik”
I also learnt from him that as per Nyaya even illusion is accepted to be real and hence nyaya is dualist in nature.
My friend quoted this verse which i do not know meaning of

> अधिष्ठानं च सदृशं तथ्यवस्तुद्वयं विना। न भ्रान्तिः भवति क्वापि
>   स्वप्नमायादिकेष्वपि।।

The quote is likely from tatva samgraha. But not sure.

**So my questions are:**

Do Naiyayikas accept 2 level of realities (regardless of what they name those realities)?

Do Naiyayikas accept that even illusion is real?